# Favicon not loading from https

Tags: 7

I have enabled `https` for my site. All images and files are served with `https` url, but favicon it is serving from `http://example.com/sites/default/files/favicon.ico` instead it should show as `https://example.com/sites/default.files/favicon.ico`. When I open the site in **Firefox** it is displaying below error message in console

> Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page
>   "http://example.com/sites/default/files/favicon.ico"[Learn More]

Suggest me a way to resolve this.

Comment: If you go to the admin for the theme, how does the favicon setting appear? Have you tried re-uploading the file?

Comment: Yes I tried but getting the same

Comment: Might be a bug in the theme code, if it's using a non-standard way of injecting the icon. Have you checked for that?

Comment: Do you have metatag module. If yes then below answer might provide the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also faced same situation where favicon is serving from `http` whereas all images including logo are serving from `https`. I am using [Metatag](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPr6Dqi9HJAhXBkpQKHSMNByIQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fth%2Fproject%2Fmetatag&usg=AFQjCNETsHYxVdLQ5g_Sx2UVkUTx_f38Pg&sig2=2UMjZRUfMz_R8puYdF6Isg) module, in the module configuration default favicon path is given as `http://example.com/sites.default/files/`, so favicon is serving from `http`. I have changed the path to `https://example.com/sites/default/files/favicon.ico`. This fixes the problem, this may also the reason in your case.

If this is the case you can change the favicon default path, go to  `https://example.com/admin/config/search/metatags/config/global` Under `favicon and touch icon tab` change the path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be some security reasons you can't upload by https:// but you can update favicon by below Process.

Please add below line into your **/yourproject_folder/sites/all/themes/your_theme_name/your_theme_name.info**

**features[] = favicon**

and place favicon.ico named files into **/yourproject_folder/sites/all/themes/your_theme_name/**

Answer (score 0):

Check this [blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) may be it is helpful to solve your problem.

**What is Mixed Content?**

> When a user visits a page served over HTTP, their connection is open
>   for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. When a user
>   visits a page served over HTTPS, their connection with the web server
>   is authenticated and encrypted with SSL and hence safeguarded from
>   eavesdroppers and MITM attacks.
>
> However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can
>   be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served
>   over HTTPS.  When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content
>   “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially
>   encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over
>   HTTP.  The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS
>   pages.
>
> What do I mean by “certain HTTP requests”?  Why wouldn’t the Mixed
>   Content Blocker just block all HTTP requests?  To answer this
>   question, I will first explain how the browser security community
>   divides mixed content into two categories; Mixed Active Content and
>   Mixed Passive Content.